# VBA Hide empty column names from x axis of graph

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, charts

I am trying to create a chart using macro from a dynamic range of values. Below is my code

```
Sub Chart()
 Dim rng As Range, cht As ChartObject, LstRow As Long, i As Long
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastCol As Long, lastC As Long, ColAddr As String
  Set sh = ActiveSheet      'use here your sheet
   LstRow = sh.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in A:A
   'Last column on the third row
   For i = 2 To LstRow
        lastC = sh.Cells(i, Cells.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If lastC > lastCol Then lastCol = lastC
   Next i
   ColAddr = sh.Cells(1, lastCol).Address 'last column address (on first row)

   Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Range("E2"), sh.Cells(LstRow, lastCol))
   Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=80, Width:=350, _
                                                                Height:=250)

   cht.chart.SetSourceData Source:=rng
   cht.chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    sh.ChartObjects(sh.ChartObjects.Count).chart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = _
                                            "='" & sh.name & "'!$F$1:" & ColAddr
End Sub
```

The output comes like  :
[image]

But I want to display only those columns in x-axis label where there is data. So basically as per my need X-Axis label should contain only labels like 2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2023 and NOT 2020,2021,2022.

Comment: You could hide the columns with no data

Comment: How do I do that. I want to do it using macro

Comment: If you have only one row of data, loop through it and hide the columns of those cells that are empty. If you have more than one row you'll have to check all of them before hiding a column